# Reference flow through page reference in apex trigger

Tags: trigger, process-builder, visual-workflow

Actually I have created one flow and used screen in it, flow should get triggered when Opportunity stage changes from anyone to Needs Analysis. Process builder cannot be used as screen flow cannot be called. Workflow used Flow trigger is a Pilot feature which I don't want to buy. Hence I would like to know is it possible to do page reference of a flow from the apex trigger.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things that we need to clear up first.

## Pilot Program

The salesforce.com pilot programs do not *cost* anything, they're early access to new features. You're not "buying" anything, and there's no extra cost (unless explicitly stated as such).

## [Define a Flow Trigger for Workflow (Pilot)](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_workflow_flow_actions.htm&language=en_US)

This feature is only available to orgs that *already have it*. You can't get it anyways. You're supposed to use the Process Builder.

## Screen Flows

*Screen Flows* are not designed to be used with automation, such as in a trigger or Process Builder. There's no convenient way to do so, nor should you attempt to do so. Flows that contains screens are only for avoiding writing Visualforce pages by using a graphical interface.

## Automation Flows

*Automation Flows* are the only correct way to use flows with Process Builder or with triggers. They are intended to run without user interaction. The limitations in play are to avoid having to present a possibly complicated API to interface with the flow.

## Flows Calling Flows

If you want to avoid designing the same logic twice, do remember that you can call one flow from another flow. This means that you should have a logic flow that performs the logic, and a graphical flow that calls the logic flow at the appropriate time. You can use the logic flow with Process Builder to trigger your logic automatically, and call it manually from another flow or from Visualforce if you'd like.

Comment: May be an absurd question but what do you mean by "This feature is only available to orgs that already have it." In my org I don't see this feature, how can I get it??

Comment: The Flow Triggers feature pilot was replaced by Process Builder which is a GA feature in Salesforce, which is why it will not be enabled for more organisations.